# Using a buffer to convert http request responses to string in Android - Not getting entire response

Tags: android, string, httpresponse, buffer-overflow, bufferedreader

I'm developing an app that posts to a site and I'm trying to store the entity response as a string. However, the string only seems to contain a small portion of the response, roughly 35 lines or so. I'm wondering if it has something to do with buffer overflow but really I am not sure. My code is below:

```
static String getResponseBody(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

    String content = null;
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) 
    {
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            if(isBlankString(line) == false)
            {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        br.close();
        content = sb.toString();
    }
    return content;
```

isBlankString just notes if a line doesn't contain any characters, as there's alot of blank lines in the response that were bugging me. I have the issue of not getting the whole response with or without this. Any body know what's going on or how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my application I use just single line to get response string from entity:

```
final String responseText =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: haha thanks, that is alot simpler. However, I think am still not getting the full response. Oddly enough, if I use Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, responseText); to view the response after I call your code, I see a good bit more of the response than if I pass the string back to the calling method and concatenate it onto a string containing other details (the status line and a list of cookies). Is it possible that I am reaching the max length of the string or something like that?

Comment: Even I am facing same problem please help

Comment: Are you sure that this is a problem with response? logcat cut strings if they are too long